# Problem with passing data to graphql from react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have username and password which I want to send to graphql backend from react on frontend. I'm using apollo client for that

on my client side I have this

```
const REGISTER_USER = gql`
  mutation RegisterUser($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    registerUser(username: $username, password: $password) {
      username,
      password
    }
  }
`;
```

And I'm calling it like this

```
registerUser({ variables: { username: values.username, password: values.password } })
```

On my server

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'user',
    fields: () => ({
        username: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
});
const Mutations = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        registerUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                username: { type: GraphQLString },
                password: { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve(username, password) {
                console.log(username, password, 123)
            }
        },
    }
})
```

The problem is - I'm passing password and username separatly as strings, but my `console.log(username, password, 123)` in mutations gives back `undefined` and full object with username, password fields.

I'm not sure where I'm doing something wrong.
All the help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So, what is the signature of the resolve function supposed to be? Why do you expect it would be passed the username and password as parameters? You can find the API reference [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#definitions)

Comment: @DanielRearden Well I'm passing down two string, my args in mutations both are ```type: GraphQLString```. Or is it because I made ```type: UserType,``` in my function?

Comment: check GraphQLFieldResolveFn arguments, compare `resolve()` usage in some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resolve` function has `source`, `args`, `context` and `info` as params. You can read more about it in [resolver function signature](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers/#resolver-function-signature).

So basically you're asking for `source` and `args`, that is why one is `undefined` and the other is the object of arguments. The way to get your variables in your resolver is:

```
const Mutations = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        registerUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                username: { type: GraphQLString },
                password: { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve: (source, args) {
                console.log(args.username, args.password)
                // HERE: you can access your arguments input as part of the 'args' object
            }
        },
    }
})
```